# How to specify bold font in VS Code editor?

Tags: windows, fonts, editor, visual-studio-code

How to specify a **bold** font in VS Code's `settings.json`? For example, I have `Envy Code R` and `Envy Code R Bold` (exact names shown in windows' font viewer) installed on my windows machine, and while

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Envy Code R"
```

setting works fine,

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Envy Code R Bold"
```

doesn't work (a fallback font is used instead).

Is that possible to do at all? There are no any other font settings like `fontWeight` or `fontStyle`. I also tried specifying other fonts with bold variants to no avail. VS Code `0.10.11` here.

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome either, which may be related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57119997/chrome-doesnt-support-font-family-arial-bold

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In your settings.json .vscode add this line:

```
"editor.fontWeight": "bold"
```

Comment: I think the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086247/2487485) provided by @tripdubroot more precisely addresses the problem the poster posed.

Comment: Hard to see how that is more precise when that answer is only for OSX and the poster is using Windows... =)

Comment: Great advice. Yeah, it doesn't answer the question directly, but it solves the problem directly! Another useful setting is "terminal.integrated.fontWeight": "bold", which has the same effect, but for the terminal.

Answer (score 25):

Here is what I did trying to solve the same issue on a Mac.
I installed the font on my Mac the usual way:

- double-click on the `.ttf` file and click on `Install Font`

The font had some variants, I wanted to use one of them on vs-code.

When you install the font on your Mac an application called `Font Book` pops up (see screenshot).

- Click on the `i` icon highlighted in the screenshot, it will give you the information of the `Postscript name` of the font.
- copy-paste this value (the `Postscript name` value) into vs-code's settings -> `Editor: Font Family` as your first item in the list.

[image: Mac Font Book Application]

Result:

[image: Result of adding font in vs-code]

Answer (score 14):

This is a bug with Atom: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3790

A workaround is to strip spaces and add a hyphen between the font name and the weight.

```
Envy Code R Bold == EnvyCodeR-Bold
```

ref: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/381#issuecomment-163356103

Comment: the workaround works only for OSX, as stated there in github comments - and indeed, I tried it on windows to no avail.. but thank you for the heads-up that it's a bug.

Comment: Good catch on the OS dependency.

Comment: I was trying to specify a font variation in macOS as well.  This modified version of the font designation worked for me.  I wanted to use `'IBM Plex Mono Medium'` and provided it as `'IBMPlexMono-Medium'`.

Answer (score 7):

**Alternative way:**

On MAC go to **Code** -> **Preferences** -> **Settings** or press shortcut **CMD** + **,**

In search bar just write font and you should find:

**Editor: Font Weight**

And from there you can choose your font weight from 100 to 900

Comment: And soon - it is in the Insiders Build, so out in v1.49 - you can choose intermediate numbers, like `350` for the `editor.fontWeight`.  Previously you were limited to one of the enum values `['normal', 'bold', '100', '200', '300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '900']`.

Comment: Although I have Roboto Mono Installed which has a wide range of weights, it only display two weights 400 or 600 if I flip through all of these, I would like a font right in between 500. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

For now in your settings.json (**ctrl+<**) .vscode add this line:

```
"editor.fontWeight": "bold",
```