# How to make current line bold in VS Code editor?

Tags: fonts, editor, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, if my caret cursor is on a given line is it possible for the code on *that line alone* to become **bold**?

Similar to how putting the following in `settings.json` allows for highlighting of the background of current line, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51262762/how-to-change-current-line-color-in-debugging-mode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938552/vs-code-vim-how-do-you-highlight-current-line):

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
      "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#404040"
    },
```

Or how putting this would make all text bold, per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085443/how-to-specify-bold-font-in-vs-code-editor):

```
"editor.fontWeight": "bold"
```

Except instead of a background modification I'd like to bold the font/text/code itself, and instead of *all* text, just the current line.  (The bolded text need not be selected, just on the same line as the caret.)

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need an extension to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely, since VSCode is a text editor, not a word processor. If your document is in markdown mode, and you have the right extension installed, Cmd/Ctrl-B does markdown.extension.editing.toggleBold, but it does that by adding/removing characters to the selected text.  E.g. for me "This is a test" becomes "**This is a test**", which is interpreted as bold.

If you want to "tag" lines of code to say they're important, something like bookmarks might work?  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alefragnani.Bookmarks

Comment: I think the bold for Markdown is done with **syntax highlighting**

Comment: Yes, get that ;_)  The point is that it modifies the actual contents/text, there's no way to add arbitrary styling, without things like a bookmark extension...

Comment: No it modifies the style of text ranges found by the "syntax" TextMate parser

Comment: @rioV8, give it a try - I think you'll find that hitting Cmd/Ctrl-B in a markdown document actually adds the \*\* to whatever is selected (or the current word if nothing is), and *then* the styling for that is applied.  Just as if you had typed the \*\* yourself.  It's sort of a fine point and not very helpful for the original question (which I think is confusing a text editor with a word processor).

Comment: yes, but it is also shown in the editor window in bold (by syntax highlighting) just like adding `_` shows the text IN the editor as italic.

Answer (score 0):

Another "not really an answer, but might be helpful" link. If you choose the whole line to "mark" it would make that line bold, or a different style.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryu1kn.text-marker

1. Features
2. Highlight/Unhighlight text from both command palette or right-click
   menu
3. Update existing highlight rules from the right-click menu
4. Jump to the next/previous location of the same highlighted pattern
   Highlight text using a regular expression